# Authenticity of a hadith regarding Jannah

Tags: hadith

Can someone help determine the grading of this hadith;

> It was narrated from Abu Umamah that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> “There is no one whom Allah will admit to Paradise but Allah will
> marry him to seventy-two wives, two from houris and seventy from his
> inheritance from the people of Hell, all of whom will have desirable
> front passages and he will have a male member that never becomes
> flaccid (i.e., soft and limp).’”
>
> [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1294400)

Did the Prophet SAW really utter the words in the last line?

Comment: If you search for it in e.g. google you can find a reference and grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere I [found this hadith](https://dorar.net/hadith/search?q=%D8%AB%D9%90%D9%86%D9%92%D8%AA%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90+%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%B3%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%92%D8%B9%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8E+%D8%B2%D9%8E%D9%88%D9%92%D8%AC%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%8B&st=a&xclude=) mentioned, it was graded as weak or *very weak*.